# How are services bound to port effected when they use LOCALHOST and 2 IP addresses are used?

Tags: wcf, binding, tcp, windows-server-2008

I have a stack of WCF services installed on a Windows 2008 R2 Standard virtual server. Many of the endpoints are bound to local host see example below:

---

endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8738/Services/Service"

---

This works at the moment as only as single local IP (192.168.20.10) is bound to the NIC.

If I add another local IP address (192.168.20.11):

1) does localhost reference mean the service port is published on both IP addresses ?

2) if not how does the OS decide which IP ?

Thank you 
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` refers to the [loopback address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) `IPv4: 127.0.0.1` or `IPv6 ::1`.

When a service is bound to a loopback address, it's only available to that host. One use case is for webservice components which are only exposed by the HTTP daemon by proxy. Adding IP addresses to an interface will make no difference to services bound to `localhost`.

When a service is intended to be made available to the network the binding is usually `*:portnumber`. This will listen on all IP addresses, so that adding another IP to the interface will result in the service being available on the new IP address too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See this is why I am confused, I understand localhost is 127.0.0.1 and the service is bound to 127.0.0.1 but i appear to be able to connect to that port from another machine. If what you suggest is true how is that possible ?

Comment: For example we host an WCF SMS service , a web app from a web server talks to it , yet the SMS service bindings all display localhost , no IP address is written in the config file.

Comment: I'd suspect that your SMS service is being exposed (proxied) by another service on the same machine.

Comment: Not so sure sorry , I have various example WCF services that are accessible using the private IP , all bindings on these services have always used LOCALHOST. Thanks for your time though. Will amend to the local IP prior to adding the new IP.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that using something like `net.tcp://localhost:4512` will not bind to the loopback address as expected but instead will listen on `0.0.0.0:4512` thus accepting connection on all ip addresses.